# How do I Access WordPress Subdomain Via FTP?

Tags: wordpress, ftp, filepath

I'm editing the style of a theme of a subdomain in my multisite network.

bnurowing.com (actually bnurowing.brightpixelstudios.co.uk).

I want to replace an orange triangle gif with a slightly darker version. The current css points to "http://bnurowing.com/wp-content/themes/theme1365/images/sub-nav-top1.gif".

So I thought I'd just insert a darker version of the .gif with the exact same filename (sub-nav-top1.gif) in the 'exact' same file path via FTP. That way the CSS would be pointing to the new version.

Turns out that I'd actually uploaded to "http://brightpixelstudios.co.uk/wp-content/themes/theme1365/images/sub-nav-top1.gif.

How do I get the image path to be on bnurowing.com? Even though it runs off the back of brightpixelstudios.co.uk?

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Bizarre, when I view the site incognito, logged out, the darker version of the image is correctly referenced as I expected it to in the first place. Guess it's just the browser using short term memory (cache) to reference the old version. (i.e, logout, delete all web browsing data - hey presto! Then login)..

Comment: There's **only one** Themes folder. There's no FTP for the subdomain. What you have is the uploads folder for each subsite at `/wp-content/blogs.dir/SITE-ID/files/`.